# Calendar control in angular 2.0

Tags: angular

We are looking a calendar control similar to the one mentioned below in Angular 2.0

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?2BFI1uwu

Plase suggest.

Thanks,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule out. They have an angular2.0 wrapper of http://fullcalendar.io/